# How to resolve sfdx installation problem in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, node.js

Can anyone help me with this npm ERROR.

```
npm install sfdx-cli --global
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'sfdx-cli@7.187.1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '>=14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v12.22.9', npm: '8.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ameer/.npm/_logs/2023-02-16T16_15_52_419Z-debug-0.log
```

I am getting this error while installing the sfdx cli in my ubuntu 22.04. I have already installed nodejs and npm even though I didn't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Your user account does not have write permissions to `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Try `sudo npm install sfdx-cli --global` if you have access and enough privileges to sudo.

Comment: @identigral using npm in sudo mode is not needed and not recommended https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3

Answer (score 0):

NPM is not correctly configured to run in none-sudo mode.

NPM should not require sudo. Running npm with sudo is highly discouraged.

This is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/how-to-fix-npm-throwing-error-without-sudo) you're looking for. I would also recommend using [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).